# How to assign a single character from a string to another string in C?

Tags: c, string, copy

I have

```
char alphabet[27] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
```

and I want to assign a random letter from the above string to a string called

```
char guess[2]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() % 28;
    char strcpy(guess, alphabet[r]);
```

I know this won't work because it will try to copy the whole `alphabet` into `guess` right?
I just want to assign a random letter to `guess` so I can create a hangman program and I want the PC to guess the letters to the secret word. In a previous version of the program, I was the one to guess the letters so I just used

```
gets(guess);
```

to do it. I want it to be the same but with the PC guessing random letters from the `alphabet` string. Is that possible?

Comment: How many letters are in *your* alphabet?

Comment: I use the whole English alphabet so 27 letters.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 2):

Just forgo any form of `strcpy`:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand() % 26;
guess[0] = alphabet[r];
guess[1] = '\0';
```

But if you want to use it just as a `char`, and not an array, just declare `char guess;` and use it as such.

Answer (score 1):

> I know this won't work because it will try to copy the whole alphabet into guess right?

Right on the "wouldn't work", but not exactly right on the why part: it will try using `alphabet[r]` as an *address*, which will cause undefined behavior.

Getting a single `char` is much simpler than that - you do not need a function, you can do this:

```
char guess = alphabet[r];
```

That's it - a single `char` can be copied with a simple assignment.

> In a previous version of the program, I was the one to guess the letters so I just used `gets(guess)`

This explains why you declared `guess` as `char[2]`, not as `char`. You do not need to do it like this in this version of the program, because you are not reading the input, so you don't need an extra spot for the null terminator.

Also note that `gets` should not be used - it is inherently unsafe, because it can easily cause buffer overruns. You should use `fgets` instead, because you can pass the size of the buffer to `fgets`, and ensure that it wouldn't go past the end of your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do something like

```
guess[0] = alphabet[r];
```

?

Comment: plus `guess[1] = '\0';` if you whant to have a NUL terminated string

Answer (score 1):

Just as you can read a single character from the array `alphabet` with `alphabet[index]` you can set a single character in the same way as well, so:

```
guess[0] = alphabet[r];
```

To make sure guess can be used as a NUL-terminated string you'll need to make sure the second char is NUL:

```
guess[1] = '\0';
```

A final bug in your code is in the following line:

```
int r = rand() % 28;
```

The 28 needs to be replaced by 26 (there are only 26 valid values).